# IdentityServer3 - Client certificate validation

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have IdentityServer3 and I'm trying to run their original samples `WebHost (minimal)` as the server and `Console Client Credentials Flow using Certificate` as the client because I want to test that the client can validate against IdS3 by using a X509 Thumbprint instead of a shared secret to get an Access Token.

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting an error response: `invalid_client`.
Apparently, it's because IdS3 doesn't receive the certificate on the incoming request, so it considers that the token request is invalid (I tested this by adding a custom `SecretParser` and checking the `environment` parameter and there's no `ssl.ClientCertificate` value which is the one `X509CertificateSecretParser` uses to parse it).

I'm just running both projects in 2 different instances of Visual Studio into IIS Express without modifying anything else on the projects. Is there anything that I'm missing on this matter? What else should I need to setup in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to enable client certificates in IIS Express.

You do this by editing this file:

.vs\config\applicationhost.config

Change

```
<access sslFlags="None" />
```

to

```
<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
```

Now IIS Express supports client certificates, but it checks if the certificate is trusted as well.

The sample certificate, Client.pfx, will not work out of the box.

You can either let Windows trust the issuer of this certificate (not reccomended) or you could load an existing certificate from the certificate store with code like this:

```
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        string thumb = "<thumbprint>";
        X509Certificate2Collection cers = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumb, false);
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        if (cers.Count > 0)
        {
            cert = cers[0];
        }
        store.Close();
```

You will also need to put the thumbprint of this certificate into the ClientSecret property in the client list on the Identity Server.

This is the sample code you will need to change:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "Client Credentials Flow Client",
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "clientcredentials.client",
                Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256()),
                        new Secret
                        {
                            Value = "<your thumbprint here>",
                            Type = Constants.SecretTypes.X509CertificateThumbprint,
                            Description = "Client Certificate"
                        },
                    },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "read",
                        "write"
                    },

                Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("location", "datacenter")
                    }
            },
```

Comment: Will this work for requests that don't have certificate and client doesn't require it (as in there's no thumbprint secret)?